# FirePower Malware Notification - Track Destination

Tags: cisco-asa, exchange-2013

Good Morning,

I received a notification from FirePower that there was a MALWARE-CNC Win.Trojan.Gh0st variant outbound connection to our exchange server.  I'm guessing there was an email sent to one of our staff that has a malicious attachment. I'd like to track who this was sent to though.  Do you know if thats possible.  I have the source IP, but the only thing the FirePower notification tells me is that it was directed to our load balancer for exchange.  Doesn't exactly tell me what mailbox it was being sent too. Is it possible to find this info?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation it appears this was generated by https://malware-hunter.shodan.io/ hitting out our Outlook Web Access Site.